# how to change the rootpassword of openLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

I inputed this cli :/usr/local/openldap/sbin/slappasswd on the terminal.And it created a cryptographic number.
But the rootpw in the slapd.conf didn't change.
why?..

Answer (score 1):

The master password is set via the configuration, in `slapd.conf` or the online configuration. It's not in the DIT, so it can't be set via `slappasswd.` But you shouldn't have any need to change it, as you shouldn't be using the master account in the first place, other than for initial configuration. The master account is for `slapd` itself, and it bypasses a lot of features. You should define administrative accounts in the DIT, give them the appopriate privileges, and use those.

Comment: Thanks for help! It's my first time to use openLDAP,i haven't master it well,so i don't know what DIT is.Would you please afford me some data about openLDAP?I have searched informations on net,but they aren't no enough detailed.

Comment: DIT is Directoy Information Tree, or the database itself. Everything you need to know about OpenLDAP is at OpenLDAP.org, and there is a very good third-party reference at http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/.